# Nodetool output when having a cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, nodetool

I have a cassandra cluster (two nodes) already set up. When I use nodetool to get the tablestats I get different values depending on where I use nodetool. Is there a way to get an output that give a representation of the entire cluster?

For example, when I use nodetool tablestats thingsboard (this is in my node 1), I get write latency: 0.015ms. And when I do the same, but in my node 2, I get write latency: 0.012ms.

Is there a way that I can get an average of this value within nodetool? Like: nodetool tablestats (node1 and node2) thingsboard ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible out of the box - all nodetool commands are using JMX of the node to which it's connected.  To have aggregated results you need to setup some monitoring system, for example, by using [Metrics Collector for Apache Cassandra (MCAC)](https://github.com/datastax/metric-collector-for-apache-cassandra), and use Prometheus to scrape data, and represent data using Grafana. You can use other systems as well - for example, scrape JMX metrics using Prometheus's JMX collector, etc.